# Dividir una cadena larga en varias cadenas

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

Estoy tratando de dividir una cadena de caracteres larga de longitud variable  en cadenas de 1000 caracteres, y asignar cada trozo de cadena a una variable en python.

```
text = "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"


t1=text[:len(text)//2]
t2=text[len(text)//2:]
```

este método el único que se me ha ocurrido, partirla en dos, pero no me sirve.
he tratado de de hacer un bucle para acceder a ciertas partes de índice y cortar pero no logro nada funcional
alguien me puede orientar un poco???
gracias

Comment: hay una pregunta muy similar

Comment: muchas gracias me ha ayudado mucho. Me falta encontrar la forma de asignar cada trozo de cadena a una variable distinta.

Comment: lo recomendable es usar un diccionario. Es mejor que hagas otra pregunta, ya que esta se aleja totalmente a lo que quieres

Comment: Asignar los pedazos a variables distintas no funciona. Necesitaras más o menos variables según el largo de la cadena. Luego, más adelante en el programa, no sobras cuales variables sirven y cuales no. Tendrás que repetir una y otra vez el mismo código para cada posible variable.